# Ansible module conditional requierment

Tags: python, ansible

I am currently writing my first Ansible module in python. I have something like:

```py
module_args = dict(
    foo=dict(type='str', required=True),
    bar=dict(type='str', required=True),
    is_bar=dict(type='bool', required=False, default=False)
)
```

Is it a way to tell Ansible that `bar` is required only if `is_bar` is set to True? Or do I need to put bar as not required and check on my own code?

Thanks

Comment: may be put `is_bar` ahead of `bar` and use do  `bar=dict(type='str', required=is_bar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/module_utils.html#ansiblemodule) `AnsibleModule()` accepts a `required_if` argument.

In your case this would mean something the following when initialising your `AnsibleModule()`:

```py
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        foo=dict(type='str', required=True),
        bar=dict(type='str'),
        is_bar=dict(type='bool', required=False, default=False),
    ),
    required_if=[
      ('is_bar', True, ('bar')),
    ]
    # ... and potentially other arguments
)
```

See also [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec) for a detailed description of how `required_if` works. For example you can define multiple arguments that are required (if another argument has been passed in), and also have mutually exclusive arguments.